# Remove duplicate files with advanced name search

Tags: mp3

I've downloaded some mp3 files (many actually) and I want to know how I can remove duplicates. The duplicates neither have exactly the same name nor the same size/contents. The similarity is in their names.  For example:

```
Calvin Harris – Blame (Feat. John Newman)
Blame - Calvin Harris
```

Is there any cmd workaround or other solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using [Anti-Twin](http://www.anti-twin.com/)  (and similar) freeware software, dont bother with CMD. Never had same issue, but I think it will work just fine.
Or try [Fast Duplicate File Finder](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-About.htm), they are claiming that they remove files by similar file name

Comment: While these links may help answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Links can become invalid over time if the linked page changes.

Comment: @CharlieRB I think the links are not disposable actually ...

Comment: I had found that program but I did not get in trouble of testing it. anyway thanks.

Answer (score 3):

#### You should compare audio files by content - not by filename

There's a straight forward, free and portable tool called [similarity](http://www.similarityapp.com/) which does this.

> Similarity rapidly scans your music collection and shows all duplicate music files you may have. The comparison powered by "acoustic fingerprint" technology considers the actual contents of files, not just tags or filenames, and thus ensures the extreme accuracy of similarity estimation. Moreover, the comparison isn’t dependent of music file format; the application supports almost every file format in full.

[image]

Comment: You are right, but the contents are not exactly similar. one of them is 4:12 minutes while another is 3:56 . These 2 files are not similar in contents. There are some "gaps" in the beginning of the first. Can this tool identify this gap ?

Comment: @TechLife [Similarity says](http://www.similarityapp.com/analysis) that duration isn't included into the rating calculation. So silence wouldn't matter. But it sounds you have two different versions of the same song. My experience was, that only the rating goes a little bit lower but it was still considered as the same song. Just try it. Its portable, free and doesn't change anything on your system

Comment: thanks I will give it a try (possibly in future!) But for now the name comparison just worked fine for me. Anyway thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

I was swimming in the cyber sea when suddenly saw this post. maybe helpful to others:
http://mp3.about.com/od/musiclibrarymaintenance/tp/Free-Duplicate-Music-File-Finders.htm

> **[1. Duplicate Music Files Finder](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/File-Management/Duplicate-Music-Files-Finder.shtml)**
>
> This program for Windows uses various techniques to find duplicate music files. It compares music files by searching for matching filenames, MP3 tags, CRC checksums, and file sizes. Duplicate Music Files Finder also comes with a built-in set of tools for managing your music files; for example, you can rename badly formatted music files, and play duplicate files to check them before deletion.
>
> **[2. Duplicate Cleaner](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/duplicate-cleaner)**
>
> This free duplicate file scanner for the Windows Platform has the facility to deep scan various music formats such as: MP3, M4A, M4P, WMA, FLAC, OGG, APE, and more. It's interface is intuitive to use and it has a good range of options to fine-tune your search; the selection assistant is particularly useful for quickly marking files for deletion based on your criteria. You can also use Duplicate Cleaner for your digital photo library; there's a nice feature to view an image by right-clicking the duplicate. To summarize, Duplicate Cleaner is a great all-rounder with impressive audio format compatibility.
>
> **[3. Similarity](http://www.music-similarity.com/)**
>
> Similarity is a stellar freeware program for searching for duplicate music files. It uses advanced algorithms that compares audio files based on sound content rather than binary patterns; Similarity also looks at MP3 tags and has an experiential mode for deep scanning. The program is compatible with a whole range of lossy and lossless audio formats such as MP3, WMA, OGG, FLAC, ASF, APE, MPC, and others. Overall, a very good software program geared towards finding duplicate music files.